# Localized ideal is generated by the functions that cut out the tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Vakil's exercise 12.6.H basically reads like this:

Let $k=\bar k$, and $p$ be a point on Spec $k[x_1,...x_m]/I$, where $I=(f_1,...,f_N)$. Assume that the tangent space at $p$ is cut out by $f_1,...,f_r$. Show that $Ik[x_1,...x_m]_p$ is generated by $f_1,...,f_r$.

My attempt at a solution was the following: to say that the tangent space is cut out by $f_1,...,f_r$ means that it suffices to take the orthogonal complement to the span of $(df_1,...,df_r)|_p$ to get the tangent space. To be precise, Vakil says that the tangent space is cut out by $f_1,...,f_r$, because the maximal nonvanishing minor of the Jacobian at $p$ is an $r\times r$ submatrix within the columns corresponding to $f_1,...,f_r$.

This means we do not need to take in addition the orthogonal complement to $(df_{r+1},...df_N)|_p$ because these are linearly dependent over $\kappa(p)=k$ with the first $r$ differentials. On the other hand, to take the differential of a function and evaluate it at $p$, is the same as modding the function by $p^2$, so we get that $$I/p^2=(\bar f_1,...,\bar f_r) \qquad\text{ over } \kappa(p)=k$$where the bar means "mod $p^2$". But this still seems pretty far from what I wanted.